# No tables are created

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Symfony I've created some Entity-classes like this one below:

But when I run

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:create
```

I only get the result:

*No Metadata Classes to process.*

So I wonder what am I doing wrong?

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="dimension")
 */

class Dimension
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $width;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $height;

//getters and setters are also created but removed from this code example

}
```

Comment: Make sure that file is in: "AppBundle\Entity\Dimension.php"

Comment: The path is src/AppBundle/Entity/Dimension.php on my local machine

Comment: Have you cleared cache?